# How to write like that picture

Tags: math-mode, cancel

I have a problem in latex. I can't write like that picture. 
how to write like that.

Please.[image]

Comment: If `xcolor` does not work, then try `color`. But this must be an old installation or it's incomplete

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use the `cancel` package, but there might be other options with `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{cancel}

\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}  % Using red as colour

\begin{document}
\large
$\cancel{\left(m2d2\right)} + \cancel{\left(d2m1\right)}$

\[\cancel{\left(m2d2\right)} + \cancel{\left(d2m1\right)}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that the even the package author himself does not recommend the usage of `cancel` ;-)